# Constructing feature vectors for clustering from row values

Tags: clustering, svm, k-nearest-neighbour, threshold, vector-fields

Thank you for some ideas regarding my question below.

**Background:**

I have an excel file with each row representing transactions (or transaction id's) in the format below and I am creating a feature vector from each such row and representing the row as follows:

```
Feature Vector = (AccountType, Channel, Amount, Balance, TransactionDestination, DestinationRiskRating)
```

I am encoding these column values as follows:

```
AccountType = (Checking, Saving) and    encoded Checking as 0, Savings as 1
Channel =   (Online, Branch, ATM)   and encoded as Online = 0, Branch = 1, ATM = 2
Amount ($$) is a Numeric value 
Balance ($$) is a Numeric value  
TransactionDestination (5 different countries with CountryCodes (1,2,3,4,5)
DestinationCountryRiskRating has three tiers of 'Low' represented as 0, 'Mid' as 1, 'High' as 2
```

So an example of an encoded feature vector could be:

```
(AccountType, Channel, Amount, Balance, TransactionDestination, DestinationRiskRating) =  
(0, 1, $50000, $20000, 4, 2)

 This feature vector translates into values ('Checking', 'Branch', $50000, $20000, 'Country#4', 'High')
```

**My question is:**

Now with an encoded feature vector for each row of the of the excel file, can I calculate the distance between the vectors using `SciKit` learn's `KMeans` or `k- nearest neighbor clustering algorithm` to cluster transactions?

I need to do this for a small proof of concept (quick and dirty) to prove that transactions can be clustered by calculating the distances between thus constructed feature vectors.

If we already know that some of these transactions were fraudulent, then I will now that the transactions in the same cluster might have a higher likelihood (with some probability) of being fraudulent? Therefore, this will probably be a case of K nearest neighbor or supervised learning.

Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "k nearest neighbor clustering". That is usually just a typo for k-means (but which does not use k-nearest but 1-nearest).

K-means is a bad choice here.

Do not use it on encoded data, and with different scales.

In your setting, 0=online,1=bank,2=ATM means that *average* of online and ATM would be bank... K-means *must* only be used when averages make sense on every attribute!

Avoid distance based approaches when you attributes have very different scales.

What you likely want to do instead is train a **classifier**, not perform clustering.